# Searching for string in a Text file and returning some string in c#

Tags: c#, search, stream, file-read

How to parse the line of text :

File.txt:

```
n:96 pts:341998 pts_time:3.79998 pos:-1 fmt:yuvj420p sar:12/11
```

and just get the time value appearing after `pts_time` .

`Expected Output :`

```
3.79998
```

How to get the expected output?? 
Any help would be really appreatiated.

Comment: It sounds like what you're really asking for isn't "searching for a string in a text file" but "breaking up and parsing a line containing space-separated key/value pairs". It's important to narrow down the bit that's causing you difficulties. So, given a string of the form `n:96 pts:341998 pts_time:3.79998 pos:-1 fmt:yuvj420p sar:12/11`, what have you tried in terms of parsing it so far?

Comment: Agree with @JonSkeet, I need to narrow down my question to parsing.

Comment: Your original question showed your working, which was much more useful and fit the site guidelines better.  Put the code back please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split `n:96 pts:341998 pts_time:3.79998 pos:-1 fmt:yuvj420p sar:12/11` with Space.

```
string[] lineParts = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
```

Get the array element which matches `pts_time` key.

```
string ptsTime = lineParts.First(p => p.StartsWith("pts_time")); // pts_time:3.79998
```

Split the `ptsTime` with `:`

```
string ptsTimeValue = ptsTime.Split(':')[1]; // 3.79998
```

Answer (score 1):

Add before `break`:

```
line = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("pts_time:")).Split(new char[] {':', ' '})[1];
```

Like this:

```
private string GetTimeFromFile(string fileName, int searchIndex) {
    //string found = string.Empty;
    string line;
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName)) {
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
            if (line.Contains(string.Format("n:" + searchIndex))) {
                line = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("pts_time:")).Split(':')[1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled fairly easily with a regular expression to pull the information you need.  You can build a pattern to match the line you're looking for and extract the specific piece of information like this:

```
string pattern = string.Format("^n:{0}\s.+\spts_time:([\d.]+)\s", searchIndex);
```

The `^n:{0}\s` section will positively identify the line you're after, the you can extract the relevant piece of data from the capture `([\d.]+)`.

Use it this way:

```
private string GetTimeFromFile(string fileName, int searchIndex)
{
    string pattern = string.Format("^n:{0}\s.+\spts_time:([\d.]+)\s", searchIndex);
    Regex re = new Regex(pattern);
    using (var file = File.OpenText(fileName))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var m = re.Match(line);
            if (m.Success)
                return m.Groups[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Another regex that might help you later is this one:

```
(?:(?<n>\w+):(?<v>\S+))
```

That will match all of the name/value pairs in the line, giving multiple match results.  With a bit of LINQ you can readily convert the results into a useful collection like this:

```
var re = new Regex(@"(?:(?<n>\w+):(?<v>\S+))");
var lineData = 
    // Get all matching terms in the source line
    re.Matches(line)
    // Convert to an enumerable we can use Select on
    .OfType<Match>()
    // Get the key/value out as a KeyValuePair
    .Select(r => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(r.Groups["n"].Value, r.Groups["v"].Value))
    // convert results to a Dictionary<string, string>
    .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

I chose `Dictionary<string, string>` as the output but you could use any collection type you prefer.  Once the values are separated out you can feed them to a factory method to create an instance of a class that represents the line's data, then do all your operations on solid classes.

Either way, if you use this then make sure you understand what the regular expression is doing and why.  They can be tricky to debug when they go wrong.  There's an [old joke](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) about that, which I won't repeat here.